# How to show transcription characteres in android

Tags: android, character, transcription

I have on my sqlite DB data with transcription characters like

```
æ β ç ð ə ħ ŋ ø θ œ χ n d ŋ b a t d s t b a t d t d t d t ẽ u e ë l n e e m n l e β e e e ĕ e é ē è ȅ
```

But some of them don't display under Android
How to display it correctly?
I need to display some another special characters from different European alphabets.

Thank for your time!

SOLVED!!! If it is interesting for somebody you can use special font for TextView, for example Lucida Sans Unicode.

Comment: In my case I handle this by using java's string replaceAll method.